# Implementing two nearly similar methods

Tags: c++

I need to implement a class with two similar methods, which are overloaded:

```
class MyClass {        
  public:              
    int myMethod(int a) {  
      // Logic here
    }
    int myMethod(int b, int c) {  
      // Logic here
    }
};
```

I want to reuse code and code is very similar for both, I am thinking about creating some generic method and just choose between them in implementation.

```
class MyClass {        
  public:    
    int myMethod(int a) {  
      myGenericMethod(a, 0, 0);
    }
    int myMethod(int b, int c) {  
      myGenericMethod(0, b, c);
    }
  private:
    int myGenericMethod(int a, int b, int c) {
      // Full logic is here
    }   
};
```

But I am still wondering if this solution is ok. Maybe there is a more elegant solution?

Comment: Without knowing what these functions, do, it looks perfectly fine to me, as the `myMethod` represents the user interface. IMO the generic method might be a protected or private function, as this is an implementation detail and is probably not supposed to be called from outside, or is it?

Comment: You have a well formulated question, but I believe this is opinion based. IMO I would prefer the second solution making the generic method private as stated by @Devolus following the DRY concept.

Comment: @Devolus, Ah, really, forgot "private"!

Comment: This solution is the way I would go to start, baring making the "helper" private

Comment: There are different way to "hide" the helper: private methods, free functions in unnamed namespace (in cpp) (only usable from within the file), `friend`...

Comment: A lot depends on the generic method. If it now needs conditionals to distinguish between the two cases, you would merely gain code reuse at the expense of legibility.